# Can I intercept a SOAP response in .NET before a content type binding mismatch ProtocolException?

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I am trying to debug some C# code I wrote to consume a web service. I'm hitting an error when receiving a response because the content type of the response doesn't match the binding. Exception snippet:

```
An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code 

Additional information: The content type text/xml of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8)
```

The web service is external so I can't change anything on that end. I know there are a lot of troubleshooting steps I can take besides this (and I have tried many, it's not as simple as changing the binding), but is there a way to view the response Message, or more info about the response, before I hit this exception? I have a custom [Message Inspector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector(v=vs.110).aspx) written with an AfterReceiveReply method in it, but this exception occurs *before* that method is hit.